# DDR interfacing with rockers3399 processor

Tags: digital-logic, memory, microprocessor, ddr, ddr3

I am using rockers 3399 processor in one of my applications. if you see page no 9 'External Memory or Storage device' section you can see the below things

*Support 2 channels, each channel is 16 or 32bits data width

Support up to 2 ranks (chip selects) for each channel; totally 4GB(max) address
space. The maximum address space of one rank in a channel is also 4GB, which is
software-configurable*

http://opensource.rock-chips.com/images/d/d7/Rockchip_RK3399_Datasheet_V2.1-20200323.pdf

My question is do I need to use 2 2GB RAM or can I use one 4GB RAM.

Comment: Have you found any RAM chip that is timing-compatible and interface-compatible?

Comment: Chips are there.I found in the reference design.In that they used 2 2GM RAM's .I would like to know why can't we use single 4GB RAM

Comment: Please link (in your question) to the chips you found that are definitely compatible.